# SolrNet: How can I use SolrNet with ending up with a long URL?

Tags: asp.net, solr, query-string, solrnet, asp.net-routing

I am very happy with SolrNet but at times the querystring becomes too long e.g. http://localhost:2136/li.aspx?k=vitamin&f=categories&fValue=Minerals&s=name (searching for vitamins, then clicked on Minerals in the category facet and opted to sort results by name)

So my question is, is there a better way to query solr (via SolrNet) without making the URL this long (and ugly). Concretely, is there another way to query solr then doing a response.redirect every time a different facet is clicked?

Thanks!

Comment: I coded my Python Solr interface to sort parameters alphabetically when generating a query string :D

Comment: @aitchnyu : this is not about the Solr query string (which is internal), he's asking about his application's query string.

Comment: My bad... I didnt infer that an ASP application was in front of Solr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really about SolrNet or Solr, since they don't dictate anything about your web application's URLs.

Assuming you're using ASP.NET (WebForms or MVC), take a look at [routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) to customize your URLs to be nicer.